# Make Posts Private in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I haven't been working with Rails for all that long and am working on creating a blog.  I would like to have a selector in the post form with "Public and "Private" and when Private is selected have that post not display unless the user is signed in.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would add a new boolean field to your `posts` table:

```
rails generate migration add_published_to_posts published:boolean
```

Add the next to this new file:

```
class AddPublishedToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :published, :boolean, default: 0
  end
end
```

This way all posts are "private" (not published) by default. Change the default value to 1 if you want posts are "public" (published) by default.

Migrate the database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

In your class, you can add this scope:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(published: true) }
  # or
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

In your controller, add something like that:

```
def index
  # With default scope
  @posts = Post.all
  # With named scope
  @posts = Post.published
end
```

Add the new field to your form and *voilá*.

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  # other fields
  = f.check_box :published
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work.  Excuse my newbieness but what should the new field look like?  I'm thinking I'm setting it up wrong.

Comment: @darkknight89 I have updated my answer. It's simple enough. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  You're right, it was easy and I realized my mistake was a simple typo that I didn't notice before.